# ayuda sobre generar un spool

Tags: oracle, spool

estoy tratando de generar un spool pero me marca erro de sintaxis

cuando inserto en la variable

```
COL Nombre_emp new_value Nombre_emp;
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TRUNC(MAX(ID_MES)),'YYYYMM'),'YYYYMM')||'.txt' Nombre_emp FROM estudiante WHERE ID_MES > 201801;

COL Mes new_value Mes;
SELECT MAX(ID_MES) Mes FROM estudiante WHERE ID_MES > 201801;
```

y lo inserto al select con el cual se generara el spool

agregando la variable de esta manera

```
(select * FROM   estudiante WHERE ID_MES = &Mes)
```

me marca error de sintaxis me podrian ayudar

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: seria bueno que agregaras el error que te genera !!